# Adobe Flex SpinnerList iconfield from XMLListCollection

Tags: xml, apache-flex, mobile, adobe

I am having problems displaying an iconField in a spinnerlist when the dataprovider is an xmllistcollection.  Originally, I started out with an ArrayCollection of objects and it displayed the iconField correctly.  I then put those same fields into an xml file.  I am reading the file in without issues, but the icon field displays blank.  My icon is stored in a field called "image" in my XML file.  If I set the labelfield = @image, it displays the path that I have stored in the xml file.  Has anyone seen this before?  I have even tried making a custom itemRenderer and adding an image with the source set to data.@image and it still does not display the image.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
            <s:SpinnerListContainer width="100%" height="180" horizontalCenter="0" focusedTextSelectionColor="#BE1E2D" focusColor="#BE1E2D" click="spnChange(event)">
            <s:SpinnerList id="spnList" height="100%" width="100%" typicalItem="999" wrapElements="true" gestureSwipe="spnList_gestureSwipeHandler(event)" gestureZoom="spnList_gestureSwipeHandler(event)" change="spnList_gestureSwipeHandler(event)" color="#000000">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:IconItemRenderer iconWidth="56" iconHeight="37" iconField="@image" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle"/>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>                   
            </s:SpinnerList>            
        </s:SpinnerListContainer>
```

JH

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i needed to change the path in the iconField to a different subdirectory.

```
<s:SpinnerList id="spnList" height="100%" width="100%" typicalItem="999" wrapElements="true" gestureSwipe="spnList_gestureSwipeHandler(event)" gestureZoom="spnList_gestureSwipeHandler(event)" change="spnList_gestureSwipeHandler(event)" color="#000000">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>                          
                        <s:IconItemRenderer iconWidth="56" iconHeight="37" **iconField="../@image"** height="100%" verticalAlign="middle"/>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:SpinnerList>
```